# Woocommerce variations add to cart not showing on mobile

Tags: jquery, wordpress, drop-down-menu, woocommerce, select-menu

I am developing my own woocommece theme and I have the following issue:

On desktop:

- I choose a colour variation from the select dropdown
- Once selected the add to basket and quantity inputs appear (using some default woocommerce jquery slide down stuff)

On Mobile:

- I choose a colour varation from the select dropdown
- **Nothing happens**. The quantity and add to basket button does not appear

Can someone point me in the right direction to resolve this?

Notes:

- I'm not using any custom select menus or scripts to change their appearance
- I have not modified any woocommerce functionality

Thanks.

Comment: It has to be a script error. Check your web browser's console.

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t modify your css or responsive layout, check your javascript code, you can have different behaviors between desktop and mobile.
Check also if the theme is compatible with woocommerce, if not you can have problems like this.